# Can the word 'formatting' be used as a noun?

Tags: grammaticality, gerunds, parts-of-speech, programming, determiners

Can the word `formatting` be used as a noun like in the following sentence:

```
Consider the formatting of this JavaScript code...
```

Or is it a gerund which should be used without an article:

```
Consider formatting of this JavaScript code...
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21161604/2842067) is the context of the example sentence.

Comment: Why should gerunds be used without articles? *I never liked painting of Turner and Constable.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I thought that using an `-ing` word with an article makes it a noun not a gerund (a gerund transformed into a noun). Correct me if I am wrong. I think it may also depend on the English grammar (perhaps, different books may have different opinions).

Comment: Your understanding is indeed wrong. A gerund is a present participle used as a noun. So every gerund is a noun *by definition*. If it is not a noun, it is not a gerund, either. An article alone does not change anything. If you drop an article in front of a noun, it is still a noun, you just get an ungrammatical sentence. Likewise, if you just slap an article in front of a random word in a sentence, you won't turn it into a noun, you'll just get an ungrammatical result.

Comment: We've had quite a few discussions on the right way to analyse -ing forms. John Lawler says: 'The distinction between the two terms "participle" and "gerund" isn't really applicable to Modern English. It's a traditional one based on Latin morphology and syntax." I'd add that the term 'gerund' is used in confusingly different ways by different people. [Quirk](http://www.wordwizard.com/phpbb3/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=23581&hilit=Quirk+gradience) prefers to consider a gradience from the deverbal noun (if available) all the way to the participle. I dropped the painting <==> He was painting a picture.

Comment: ...I'm happy with the Quirk gradience (though it's not perfect – models in English never seem to be). 'Velecka GerundTranslation Thesis - Scribd' (I can't link) gives an overview of different approaches to the analysis of -ing forms. If I had to use the term gerund, I'd reserve it for -ing forms nearer (but not at) the nounal end of the cline: _His painting_ (= occupation/hobby not picture) _is not going to make him any money_.

Comment: @RegDwigнt I stadied English by a grammar book that was initially published in 1950s in the USSR. It's an exceptionally good book but it's different from modern English grammars. I am curious what are the roots of this difference. I'd like to update my knowledge, but I have not had a chance so far. This book makes a very clear distinction between present participles, gerunds and nouns.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth According to that book, a noun can have an article, can be plural, and can be modified by an adjective (`the expensive paintings`). A gerund, on the other hand, has a tense, voice, can have an object, and can be modified by an adverb (`Painting quickly is...`, `Painting a picture is...`). So it's the point of view from which I made my question :)

Comment: The snag is that 'John's slowly painting the patio infuriates me' is grammatical, and here painting has a properties you would only expect nouns to possess, **and** properties you would only expect verbs to possess. Some nouns do not have plurals.

Comment: @Edwin, I understand what you are saying in you comments. I agree with you. According to my old grammar book `painting` would be a gerund because it has an object (`the patio`), and it is modified by an adverb (`slowly`).

Comment: Different grammar books have often disagreed or at least used different terminology and approaches. ACGEL (Quirk et al) and CGEL (Pullum & Huddleston) have been very valuable. While I believe that there will never be a definitive treatment (J Lawler recommends McCawley), there have been major steps forward in analyses over the last 60 years, so that some older treatments would be regarded as outdated or even shown to be inaccurate / misleading. The various views of what a 'gerund' is have not, to my knowledge, been harmonised. So I avoid the term.

Comment: @Edwin, thank you for clarifying it. I've being wondering for a while why that book is so different from other grammar books. I have already run into many differences. Gerunds and participles are just one more thing. I've been shopping around for a while trying to find a substitute for it, but the best I could find so far is *Carter, McCarthy - Cambridge Grammar of English*. This book has twice as many pages as my old one with seemingly twice as little information in it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Formatting can be used as a noun. In American English, the article signals that that the next word is a noun.

Leave out the "the" and your sentence becomes an aborted present participle. IOW the phrase "Consider formatting..." is in the imperative case—you are ordering the reader to write the code in an alternate way.

Comment: "In American English, the article signals that the next word is a noun." is a weird thing to say, for two reasons. First, you are suggesting that articles in non-American English are used differently. Secondly and most importantly, you suggest that "next" is a noun. Your statement is a direct contradiction of itself.

Comment: So 'the more the merrier' is only used in Merry Olde England?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth According to my dictionary, `the` in `the more the merrier` in an adverb. Again, different grammars may have different opinions. But it's not an article because it's used in a very different way here.

Comment: @RegDwigнt An article can be used before a noun or a noun phrase (e.g., `next word`). Maybe, saying just "a noun" is a reasonable simplification.

Comment: @Alexey This is probably the most unjustifiable saddling of a word with the tag 'adverb' known to mankind. And there are plenty of unjustifiable ones. The fixed expression is probably an elision from 'the more people who turn up, the merrier the party will be' or something similar, where the usage of the article is unremarkable. Cobuild have a 100+ page monograph on articles, so they must think there are a fair number of usages. We could go on to argue whether 'article' is a dustbin class, of course. 'The article signals that what follows is usually a noun group' works.

Answer (score 1):

Participles are wondrous works of miracles. They transform verbs into nouns or adjectives, or even adverbs.

verb: paint

> He paints horses and lighthouses.

Present participle as noun = gerund.

Gerund related indirectly to the verb (Noun describing the consequence/product of the verb):

> His paintings sell very well.

Gerund related directly to the verb (Noun describing the verb):

> His painting of horses and houses is a lucrative business.

Present participle used as adjective:

> All running dogs die.
>   /* *Running Dogs* is term used on traitors who collaborated with the Japanese invasion of south-east and far-east Asia. Original usage [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-tank_dog), which was then used pejoratively by the Resistance militias on traitors.  */
>
> I found the smoking gun.

Present participle used as adverb, i.e. as a modifier to a verb. I think some people dispute this is a form of adverb, but the participle does modify the verb, doesn't it?:

> He ran panting.
>   She eats talking.
>   He speaks sitting.
>   He was caught stealing, he was caught red-handed.

**Use *generalizer* or specifier?**

The question should not be asked whether you should use a *generalizer* or specifier on a participle, or leave it as default (unspecified). Do not put the horse behind the cart. First decide if you are using a verb as a verb, a noun participle, adjectival participle or as adverbial participle. Once you have decided that, blind yourself to the fact that you are using a participle, and then ask yourself if a generalizer or specifier should be used on that verb, noun, adjective, adverb.

- default: Running dogs will die for their sins.
- generalizer: **All** running dogs will die for their sins.
- generalizer: **A** running dog will die for his sins.
- generalizer: **Any** running dog will die for his sins.
- generalizer: **Few** running dogs will die for their sins.
- specifier: **Their** sinning had caused the torture and execution of many of their compatriots in the war.
- specifier: **Her** running private errands for her boss is considered unethical exploitation by her boss.
- generalizer: **A** painting is not a salable commodity at current market conditions.
- specifier: **The** painting is of high quality.

Let's look at the word *format*:

- default: Formatting is not required. Jackets are also not required.
- default: He considers formatting as unnecessary. He also considers jackets unnecessary.
- generalizer: He considers **any** formatting extraneous.
- specifier: **Your** formatting is ugly.

Comment: I don't think many people would class 'painting/s' in 'his paintings sell well' as a gerund. It has full noun status, accepting articles and relevant adjectives, and having a plural form. Since it is derived (or perhaps converted) from the verb 'paint' (or the participle 'painting'), but has achieved full membership of the word class _nouns_, it is called a **deverbal noun**.

Comment: Thx Edwin, the gerund should not involve the nominative, but I'll leave it unedited, with the notes here.

Answer (score 0):

*Formatting* is a gerund - the present participle of a verb used as a noun. So *the* can be used with it, just like any other noun. A gerundive is where the present participle of a verb is used as an adjective. For example, '*running* shoes' is a gerundive (adjective) but 'I like *running*' is a gerund (noun).